# how can I query data form google datastore - json api - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-datastore

I have a tiny project on school that has only two "kinds" to store :Site - Position. Each of them has only a string content.

My problem that I want to get ALL the stored data from datastore of these two kinds from javascript file.

I tried the following:

```
function getData(syncedData) {
        // reset the observable
        syncedData();

        // set the ajax
        var options = {
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/{my-project-id}/runQuery?key=AIzaSyCHeg3tkyEENxAXKsl1xilX19BreDxWFzg',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'application/json',
            data:'{ "query": { }}'
        };

        // call the ajax
        return $.ajax(options)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        // handle the ajax callback
        function querySucceeded(data) {
            syncedData(data);
            log('Sync data succeeded', sites, true);
        }

        function queryFailed(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            log('Sync data Error. ' + textStatus, jqXHR, true);
        }

    }
```

where the "key=AIzaSyCHeg3tkyEENxAXKsl1xilX19BreDxWFzg" is API Key I created as Public API access from Cloud Console; **I really need any one can query this results.**

But using the above gives me **401 (Unauthorized)** at Chrome Console.

How can I query these results and make it PUBLIC;

Must I use OAuth API? any clear steps of using 'not the google-docs'?! and how to make it PUBLIC ACCESSED?!

Comment: Is your question asking how to circumvent google's API access?

Comment: @Charlie Yes, if I can.

Comment: That seems awfully shady. The authentication is there for a reason.

Comment: So how can I do such auth, i didn't get it from google docs? any clear/simple explanation?